# Creating a timer winform application using only delegates and events [WITHOUT TIMER OBJECT]

Tags: c#, winforms, events, timer, delegates

While using timers, stopwatches and threads is the standard way, I was wondering if there was a way to create a Winform Application in c# which had a label with initial value as 0 and which automatically kept on incrementing once a button is clicked and when the same button is clicked again it should pause. Personally, I feel that the trick is to use multicast delegates. But I am stuck as to how to proceed.

NOTE: Possible use of method callback and InvokeRequired().

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to use timers to solve this? You could use a thread or task with a delay, but the answer really isn't multicast delegates here.

Comment: Yes, I don't wish to use timer or stopwatch or threads to do this. I wish to know if I can increment the label value continuously using button_click event

Comment: Is this a purely "want to know if I can do it" question, or is there a valid reason for the aversion to threads and tasks? If you want to call a method multiple times with a delay you need a loop, but you can't loop on the main thread without locking it up, so I don't know of a way to re-call the click event handler with a delay without using a timer, thread, or task and not lock up the UI.

Comment: I have been creating a simple UI which has a few limitations hence I really cannot use threads and stopwatches. I need to increment the label value like a counter

Comment: Do you want predictable delay between updates or is a random timing just fine?

Comment: Using `StopWatch` or threads are not appropriate tools for solving this problem.  They're not the "standard" solution.  They're inappropriate uses of those tools.  A `Timer` on the other hand is exactly the right tool for this job.

Comment: You could call out to the OS's hooks for notifications based on the system clock, if you really wanted to not use a `Timer`, but at that point you're just re-writing the `Timer` class for no productive reason.  Trying to not actually use the system clock at all is just not going to feasibly work, unless you're expecting to hear something where you, say, do a network request to an external server to ask it for the time  and try to use that.  Of course, if you're looking for something that does exactly what a `Timer` does but that has a different name, there are alternatives (`Task.Delay`).

Comment: I need it to be done using delegation

Answer (score 0):

this code dose not use timer or stopwatch.
i have wrote a simple class for you, forgive me if its not so standard because im so lazy for now :)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    CancellationTokenSource src;
    CancellationToken t;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //start incrementing
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Start.Enabled = false;
        this.Cancel.Enabled = true;
        this.src = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.t = this.src.Token;


        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
                {
                    Task.Delay(500);
                    var txt = int.Parse(this.Display.Text) + 1;
                    return (txt);
                }, this.t);
                var result = await tsk;
                this.Display.Text = result.ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    // Stop incrementing
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.src.Cancel();
        this.Cancel.Enabled = true;
        this.Start.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I do not want timers at all. I can easily use timers but the requirements for the Ui do not permit me to use timers, stopwatches or threads as well.

Comment: i think he gave you the correct answer but mission imposibole without thread if you want your UI keep responding with,,, if you dont you mean that you should make a for loop for increment with a small flag to increase or not which will be changed on button pressing,,, and inside the loop you can add thread.sleep(100) which will freez your app !!!

Comment: I have good reason to believe that it can be done using events and delegation.

Comment: i have changed the code a little bit to fit what you want.

Comment: Task is from System.Threading, and I believe it uses a timer behind the scenes, so I don't think this meets OPs requirements.

Comment: we are talking about time periods. how can you measure time without time? O.O

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure **why** you think this can be done with your restrictions in place.  If you want a **delay** in-between your "events", then you need to use some kind of **Timer**, or some kind of **thread** (classic Thread or some kind of Task) that has a delay within it...no way around that.

Here's another approach that'll probably violate your restrictions:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Int64 value = -1;
    private bool Paused = true;
    private int IntervalInMilliseconds = 100;
    private System.Threading.ManualResetEvent mre = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
    }

    private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(delegate ()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                value++;
                label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    label1.Text = value.ToString();
                });
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(IntervalInMilliseconds);
                mre.WaitOne();
            }
        });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (Paused)
        {
            mre.Set();
        }
        else
        {
            mre.Reset();
        }
        Paused = !Paused;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

USE an EVENT.

If you can not use timers  or threads, then how about creating a do while loop that executes an event.
Some PSEUDO code is below - it should give you the idea..

```
bool IWantEvents = false;
public event EventHandler<myHandler> myNonTimerEvent ;

FormStart()
{
 this.myNonTimerEvent += new MyNonTimerEventHandler();
IWantEvents = true;
Do
{
.. do some weird stuff - set IWantEvents False on condition ..
}
while(IWantEvents)
}

MyNonTimerEventHandler()
{
.. Do what I would do if I was using a timer event.
}
```

Comment: in this method MyNonTimerEventHandler() you would update your UI, much like any other event method. 
Your Do While method is the "timer like function", where on condition you trigger the event myNonTimerEvent.  You exit [Stop] the Do While - by setting IWantEvents to false , as long as that is true it will loop the do While and given the conditions you look for in the do while , raise the myNonTimerEvent . A timer has tick intervals - to simulate that, in Do While put empty for (i = 0; i< 10000;i++) count.